# What does android:stretchMode actually do?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am having an issue with my gridView row height(it is not consistent, it's getting smaller as I scroll down). I was reading other question/answers here and this android:stretchMode is frequently proposed. Since I am new in gridView.

**What does `android:stretchMode` actually do?**

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode) from the android developer  platform,
   `android:stretchMode` defines how columns should stretch to fill the available empty space, if any.

Must be one of the following constant values.

`none` Stretching is disabled.

`spacingWidth`: The spacing between each column is stretched.

`columnWidth`:  Each column is stretched equally.

`spacingWidthUniform`:  The spacing between each column is uniformly stretched..